# Trying to make a lexer in C and the output is not desirable

Tags: c, lexer

I have been trying to make a programming language. I did some research and found out that I need to build a lexer, after some more painful research, I came up with a lexer written in C. but when I run make, and run the output file, the output is good till the first line (refer below) but the next line is not desirable.

**lexer.h**

```
#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H
#include "token.h"

typedef struct LEXER_STRUCT {
    char c;
    unsigned int i;
    char *contents;

} lexer_T;

// init method
lexer_T *init_lexer(char *contents);
void lexer_advance(lexer_T *lexer);
void lexer_skip_whitespace(lexer_T *lexer);
token_T *lexer_get_next_token(lexer_T *lexer);
token_T *lexer_collect_string(lexer_T *lexer);
token_T *lexer_advance_with_token(lexer_T *lexer, token_T *token);
token_T *lexer_collect_id(lexer_T *lexer);
char *lexer_get_current_char_as_string(lexer_T *lexer);

#endif
```

**lexer.c**

```c
#include "include/lexer.h"
#include "include/token.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

lexer_T *init_lexer(char *contents)
{
    lexer_T *lexer = calloc(1, sizeof(struct LEXER_STRUCT));
    lexer->contents = contents;
    lexer->i = 0;
    lexer->c = contents[lexer->i];

    return lexer;
}

void lexer_advance(lexer_T *lexer)
{
    if (lexer->c != '\0' && lexer->i < strlen(lexer->contents))
    {
        lexer->i += 1;

        lexer->c = lexer->contents[lexer->i];
    }
}

void lexer_skip_whitespace(lexer_T *lexer)
{
    while (lexer->c == ' ' || lexer->c == 10)
    {
        lexer_advance(lexer);
    }
}

token_T *lexer_get_next_token(lexer_T *lexer)
{
    while (lexer->c != '\0' && lexer->i < strlen(lexer->contents))
    {
        if (lexer->c == ' ' || lexer->c == 10)
        {
            lexer_skip_whitespace(lexer);
        }

        if (isalnum(lexer->c))
            return lexer_collect_id(lexer);

        if (lexer->c == '"')
        {
            lexer_collect_string(lexer);
        }

        switch (lexer->c)
        {
        case ';':
            return lexer_advance_with_token(lexer, init_token(TOKEN_SEMI, lexer_get_current_char_as_string(lexer)));
            break;
        case '=':
            return lexer_advance_with_token(lexer, init_token(TOKEN_EQUALS, lexer_get_current_char_as_string(lexer)));
            break;
        case '(':
            return lexer_advance_with_token(lexer, init_token(TOKEN_LBRACK, lexer_get_current_char_as_string(lexer)));
            break;
        case ')':
            return lexer_advance_with_token(lexer, init_token(TOKEN_RBRACK, lexer_get_current_char_as_string(lexer)));
            break;
        }
    }
    return (void *)0;
}

token_T *lexer_advance_with_token(lexer_T *lexer, token_T *token)
{
    lexer_advance(lexer);
    return token;
}

token_T *lexer_collect_string(lexer_T *lexer)
{
    char *value = calloc(1, sizeof(char));

    while (lexer->c != '"')
    {
        char *s = lexer_get_current_char_as_string(lexer);
        value = realloc(value, (strlen(value) * strlen(s) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcat(value, s);
        lexer_advance(lexer);
    }

    lexer_advance(lexer);

    return init_token(TOKEN_STRING, value);
}

token_T *lexer_collect_id(lexer_T *lexer)
{
    char *value = calloc(1, sizeof(char));

    while (isalnum(lexer->c))
    {
        char *s = lexer_get_current_char_as_string(lexer);
        value = realloc(value, (strlen(value) * strlen(s) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcat(value, s);

        lexer_advance(lexer);
    }

    lexer_advance(lexer);

    return init_token(TOKEN_STRING, value);
}

char *lexer_get_current_char_as_string(lexer_T *lexer)
{
    char *str = calloc(2, sizeof(char));
    str[0] = lexer->c;
    str[1] = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

**main.c** (this is the file im compiling)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "include/lexer.h"

int main() {
    lexer_T *lexer = init_lexer(
        "var name = \"thickduckplayz\";\n"
        "print(name)"
    );
    token_T *token = (void*)0;

    while ((token = lexer_get_next_token(lexer)) != (void*)0)
    {
        printf("TOKEN(%d, %s)\n", token->type, token->value);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image: The Bug]

For each time, it seems to put some random characters, is there like a memory leak because one time I saw a directory. I can provide more info if you want and [the github repo is here.](https://github.com/Thickduck/duckscript)

Comment: This is neither minimal, nor reproducible because it is not compilable... Anyway having `init_token` not returning anything is an evidence that you do not use unit testing and do not pay attention to warning messages from your compiler... Another immediate possible problem is that you pass a string literal as a `char *` while it should be a `const char *`: modifying a string literal explicitely invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: After a second look at you GitHub repo, I can only tell you that it is time to learn how to use a debugger. There are a lot of little errors in your code that you would immediately find by simply single stepping through it.

Comment: I don't have much experience using debuggers because I use vim to code, should I be switching to clion? Or vscode?

Comment: And also, the compiler didn't give any sort of warning about this.

Comment: CLion is a very nice product, but AFAIK it is not free. VSCode is correct, but its initial configuration requires to carefully follow a good tutorial. But `gdb` is a correct debugger if you are used to vim. Anyway, building a compiler is a rather big project, and hoping to write it without  tons of hidden errors is *brave* is you do not use a unit test framework to make sure that low level functions do what they should. A lot are available in Linux world, but Google Test seems to have a rather good reputation.

Comment: To try to help you further, your current lexer is a bit feature poor, because keywords and identifiers are merged with literal strings. While the distinction can be latter delegated to the parser (I even saw once a parser using only simple characters as tokens, sigh...), it is more commonly processed at the lexer level.

Answer (score 1):

In **token.c** you don't ever return anything from `init_token` which miraculously isn't breaking things, but should still be fixed. Using `calloc` is also unnecessary when you initialize the value of each field so it can be replaced with `malloc`.

```
token_T *init_token(int type, char *value)
{
    token_T *token = malloc(sizeof(struct TOKEN_STRUCT));
    token->type = type;
    token->value = value;
    return token;
}
```

In **lexer.c** you also never return the result of `lexer_collect_string` in `lexer_get_next_token` which is why you are not getting the results you expect and instead whatever happens to be left in the RAX register being read as the token address. So in `lexer_get_next_token` you should change the third `if` statement to

```
if (lexer->c == '"')
{
    return lexer_collect_string(lexer);
}
```

I'd also advise changing `gcc $(files) $(flags) -o $(exec)` in your makefile to `gcc -Wall $(files) $(flags) -o $(exec)` to avoid things like this in the future.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tips. But what is -Wall? I'm being annoying ikr but I'm pretty new to c, like 2 months

Comment: It causes gcc to enable most of the warning checking. You can see exectly what warning checks they are and the different warning options [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the wording of your question, it sounds like your goal is not to learn how to write a lexer, but to build an actual language. In that case you might find it easier to use a parser generator, which will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you.

If you are implementing your language in C, the classic tools are `lex` (which generates a lexer) and `yacc` (which generates a parser). Today, people mostly use [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex) in place of `lex`, and [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison) in place of `yacc`. Here is an example of a lexer and parser for a C-like language built using these tools:

https://github.com/wkz/ply/blob/master/src/libply/lexer.l

https://github.com/wkz/ply/blob/master/src/libply/grammar.y

(Full disclosure: I'm the author)

Outside of C, there are other interesting tools available, [pest.rs](https://pest.rs) for example is pretty easy to get going with if you are in to Rust.

Comment: Can you let me know how to get the lex and yacc tools? I've tried googling them and I can't seem to find them.

Comment: Like I said, the most commonly used variants today are flex and bison. Both of them are hyperlinked in my answer, so you can get them from there. Depending on your OS, they are also probably available from your system's package manager.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- in `lexer_get_next_token()`, you should return `lexer_collect_string(lexer);` when the current character is `'"'`.
- in `lexer_collect_string()`, you should first advance to the next character to skip the initial `"`.
- in `lexer_collect_string()`, you should test for the end of string. As coded you have an infinite loop if the string is unterminated.
- in `lexer_collect_id()` you call `lexer_advance()` after the last identifier character, potentially skipping the next token.
- you should use `'\n'` instead of `10` for readability
- you compute `strlen(lexer->contents)` far too many times. You should just test if `lexer->contents[lexer->i] != '\n'` or store the length when you initialize the lexer.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//#include "include/token.h"
//#include "include/lexer.h"

enum {
    TOKEN_SEMI,
    TOKEN_COMMA,
    TOKEN_EQUALS,
    TOKEN_LBRACK,
    TOKEN_RBRACK,
    TOKEN_STRING,
    TOKEN_NUMBER,
    TOKEN_ID,
};

typedef struct TOKEN_STRUCT {
    int type;
    char *value;
} token_T;

token_T *init_token(int token, char *value) {
    token_T *tok = calloc(1, sizeof(sizeof *tok));
    tok->type = token;
    tok->value = value;
    return tok;
}

const char *token_type(int type) {
    switch (type) {
    case TOKEN_SEMI:    return "SEMI";
    case TOKEN_COMMA:   return "COMMA";
    case TOKEN_EQUALS:  return "EQUALS";
    case TOKEN_LBRACK:  return "LBRACK";
    case TOKEN_RBRACK:  return "RBRACK";
    case TOKEN_STRING:  return "STRING";
    case TOKEN_NUMBER:  return "NUMBER";
    case TOKEN_ID:      return "ID";
    default:            return "Unknown";
    }
}

typedef struct LEXER_STRUCT {
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned int i, len;
    const char *contents;
} lexer_T;

lexer_T *init_lexer(const char *contents);
void lexer_advance(lexer_T *lexer);
token_T *lexer_get_next_token(lexer_T *lexer);
token_T *lexer_collect_single_char(lexer_T *lexer, int token_type);
token_T *lexer_collect_string(lexer_T *lexer);
token_T *lexer_collect_number(lexer_T *lexer);
token_T *lexer_collect_id(lexer_T *lexer);

lexer_T *init_lexer(const char *contents) {
    lexer_T *lexer = calloc(1, sizeof(struct LEXER_STRUCT));
    lexer->contents = contents;
    lexer->len = strlen(contents);
    lexer->i = 0;
    lexer->c = contents[lexer->i];
    return lexer;
}

void lexer_advance(lexer_T *lexer) {
    if (lexer->i < lexer->len) {
        lexer->i += 1;
        lexer->c = lexer->contents[lexer->i];
    }
}

token_T *lexer_collect_single_char(lexer_T *lexer, int token_type) {
    char *str = calloc(2, sizeof(char));
    str[0] = lexer->c;
    str[1] = '\0';
    lexer_advance(lexer);
    return init_token(token_type, str);
}

token_T *lexer_collect_string(lexer_T *lexer) {
    char *value = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    unsigned int len = 0;

    lexer_advance(lexer);
    while (lexer->c != '\0' && lexer->c != '"') {
        value = realloc(value, (len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        value[len++] = lexer->c;
        lexer_advance(lexer);
    }
    value[len] = '\0';

    if (lexer->c == '"')
        lexer_advance(lexer);

    return init_token(TOKEN_STRING, value);
}

token_T *lexer_collect_id(lexer_T *lexer) {
    char *value = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    unsigned int len = 0;

    while (isalnum(lexer->c) || lexer->c == '_') {
        value = realloc(value, (len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        value[len++] = lexer->c;
        lexer_advance(lexer);
    }
    value[len] = '\0';
    return init_token(TOKEN_ID, value);
}

token_T *lexer_collect_number(lexer_T *lexer) {
    char *value = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    unsigned int len = 0;

    while (isdigit(lexer->c) || lexer->c == '.') {
        value = realloc(value, (len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        value[len++] = lexer->c;
        lexer_advance(lexer);
    }
    value[len] = '\0';
    return init_token(TOKEN_NUMBER, value);
}

token_T *lexer_get_next_token(lexer_T *lexer) {
    while (lexer->c != 0) {
        if (lexer->c == ' ' || lexer->c == '\n') {
            lexer_advance(lexer);
            continue;
        }
        if (isalpha(lexer->c) || lexer->c == '_')
            return lexer_collect_id(lexer);

        if (isdigit(lexer->c))
            return lexer_collect_number(lexer);

        if (lexer->c == '"')
            return lexer_collect_string(lexer);

        switch (lexer->c) {
        case ';':  return lexer_collect_single_char(lexer, TOKEN_SEMI);
        case ',':  return lexer_collect_single_char(lexer, TOKEN_COMMA);
        case '=':  return lexer_collect_single_char(lexer, TOKEN_EQUALS);
        case '(':  return lexer_collect_single_char(lexer, TOKEN_LBRACK);
        case ')':  return lexer_collect_single_char(lexer, TOKEN_RBRACK);
        }
    }
    return (void *)0;
}

int main() {
    lexer_T *lexer = init_lexer("var name = \"thickduckplayz\";\n"
                                "print(name, 1)");
    token_T *token = (void*)0;

    while ((token = lexer_get_next_token(lexer)) != (void*)0) {
        printf("TOKEN(%s, '%s')\n", token_type(token->type), token->value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: >in lexer_collect_id() you call lexer_advance() after the last identifier character, potentially skipping the next token.

This seemed to break things even more.